# Prove $(A \setminus B) \times C = (A \times C) \setminus (B \times C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

However. I am stucked with this --> [image]

Comment: Ummm... are you dealing with cross products of vectors, perhaps?

Comment: Last is $(x,y) \notin B \times C$ and you are done.

Comment: To the people voting down.... chill.  This person is new. Try suggesting an edit or tell them why this breaks our social norms.

Comment: I think you wanted to use "\setminus" rather than $-$.  The notation you actually used can be confused with a vector cross product.

Comment: Your problem is a special case of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717300/proving-a-b-times-c-d-a-times-c-b-times-c-a-times-d/3717324#3717324) when $D=\varnothing$, so you can use the same methods there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Your second to last step is
$$
(x\in A)\wedge (y\in C)\wedge (x\in \neg B)\wedge (y\in C) 
$$
which is true if and only if as
$$
(x\in A)\wedge (y\in C)\wedge (x\in \neg B)\tag 1
$$
Now, start working from the other side. Note
$$
\begin{align}
(x,y)\in (A\times C)- (B\times C)
&\iff ((x,y)\in A\times C)\wedge ((x,y)\notin (B\times C)
\\
&\iff (x\in A)\wedge (y\in C)\wedge \neg(x\in B\wedge y\in C)
\\
&\iff (x\in A)\wedge (y\in C)\wedge (x\in \neg B\vee y\in \neg C)
\end{align}
$$
Now, recall that $\wedge$ distributes over $\vee$ (i.e. $p\wedge (q\vee r)\iff (p\wedge q)\vee (p\wedge r)$), and continue to manipulate that last expression until it is equal to $(1)$.